Struggling to get mathematical model to work
I am trying to mimic a mathematical model based on the following model documentation.
4.1.1.4 Exposure to Vapour: Evaporation
https://www.rivm.nl/bibliotheek/rapporten/2017-0197.pdf


Python script:
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ExposureToVapourEvaporation:
    def __init__(self):
        # Input parameters
        self.frequency = 197  # per year
        self.exposure_duration = 0.75  # minute
        self.product_amount = 500  # g (amount of diluted product applied on a surface)
        self.weight_fraction_substance = 0.2  # fraction in the product
        self.room_volume = 1  # m³
        self.ventilation_rate = 0.5  # per hour
        self.inhalation_rate = 22.9 / 1000  # m³/min (converted from L/min)
        self.vapour_pressure = 0.0106  # Pa
        self.molecular_weight = 46.1 / 1000  # kg/mol (converted from g/mol)
        self.release_area = 0.002  # m²
        self.release_duration = 0.3  # minute
        self.application_temperature = 20 + 273.15  # K (converted from °C)
        self.mass_transfer_coefficient = 10 / 3600  # m/s (converted from m/h)
        self.body_weight = 9.8  # kg
        
        # Optional parameters
        self.is_product_used_in_dilution = True
        self.dilution = 1  # times (only used if is_product_used_in_dilution is True)
        self.molecular_weight_matrix = 22 / 1000  # kg/mol (converted from g/mol)
        self.is_pure_substance = True
        
        # Derived parameters
        self.is_constant_surface_area = True
        self.weight_fraction_solution = self.calculate_weight_fraction_solution()

    def calculate_weight_fraction_solution(self):
        if self.is_product_used_in_dilution:
            return self.weight_fraction_substance / self.dilution
        return self.weight_fraction_substance

    def calculate_equilibrium_vapour_pressure(self):
        return self.vapour_pressure

    def evaporation_ode(self, y, t):
        A_air, A_prod = y
        K = self.mass_transfer_coefficient
        P_eq = self.calculate_equilibrium_vapour_pressure()
        P_air = A_air * 8.314 * self.application_temperature / (self.molecular_weight * self.room_volume)
        
        if t < self.release_duration * 60:  # During release
            dA_air_dt = K * self.release_area * (self.molecular_weight / (8.314 * self.application_temperature)) * (P_eq - P_air) - (self.ventilation_rate / 3600) * self.room_volume * A_air
            dA_prod_dt = -dA_air_dt

        elif t == self.release_duration * 60:  # At the exact end of release
            dA_air_dt = 100 * K * self.release_area * (self.molecular_weight / (8.314 * self.application_temperature)) * (P_eq - P_air) - (self.ventilation_rate / 3600) * self.room_volume * A_air
        
        else:  # After release
            dA_air_dt = -(self.ventilation_rate / 3600) * self.room_volume * A_air
            dA_prod_dt = 0
        
        if A_prod <= 0:
            dA_prod_dt = 0
            dA_air_dt = -(self.ventilation_rate / 3600) * self.room_volume * A_air
        
        return [dA_air_dt, dA_prod_dt]

    def solve_evaporation(self):
        t = np.linspace(0, self.exposure_duration * 60, 1000)  # seconds
        t = np.sort(np.unique(np.append(t, self.release_duration * 60)))  # Ensure we have a point at the end of release
        y0 = [0, (self.product_amount / 1000) * self.weight_fraction_solution]  # kg
        solution = odeint(self.evaporation_ode, y0, t)
        return t, solution

    def calculate_metrics(self):
        t, solution = self.solve_evaporation()
        A_air = solution[:, 0]
        
        concentrations = A_air / self.room_volume * 1e6  # Convert to mg/m³
        mean_concentration = np.mean(concentrations)
        peak_concentration = np.max(concentrations)
        
        # Calculate TWA 15 min
        twa_15_min = mean_concentration if self.exposure_duration <= 15 else np.mean(concentrations[-int(15*60/self.exposure_duration):])
        
        # Calculate daily and yearly averages
        daily_average = mean_concentration * (self.exposure_duration / 1440)
        yearly_average = daily_average * (self.frequency / 365)
        
        # Calculate doses
        event_dose = (mean_concentration * self.inhalation_rate * self.exposure_duration) / self.body_weight
        day_dose = event_dose  # Assuming one event per day
        
        metrics = {
            "mean_event_concentration": mean_concentration,
            "peak_concentration_twa_15_min": twa_15_min,
            "mean_concentration_day": daily_average,
            "year_average_concentration": yearly_average,
            "external_event_dose": event_dose,
            "external_day_dose": day_dose
        }
        
        return metrics, t, concentrations

    def plot_air_concentration(self, t, concentrations):
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        plt.plot(t / 60, concentrations)  # Convert time to minutes
        plt.axvline(x=self.release_duration, color='r', linestyle='--', label='End of Release')
        plt.axvline(x=self.exposure_duration, color='g', linestyle='--', label='End of Exposure')
        plt.title('Air Concentration Over Time')
        plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
        plt.ylabel('Concentration (mg/m³)')
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

# Create an instance of the model and calculate metrics
model = ExposureToVapourEvaporation()
metrics, t, concentrations = model.calculate_metrics()

print("Calculated Results:")
for key, value in metrics.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value:.2e} mg/m³" if "concentration" in key else f"{key}: {value:.2e} mg/kg bw")

# Plot the air concentration over time
model.plot_air_concentration(t, concentrations)

The expected result is:

Current:

I have been trying to get the maths to work but just doesn't look right and I wonder if the documentation might be wrong.

One thing to start with is to fix your y-scale. The "expected" graph uses a linear scale with a grid step of 0.000005. Your code on the other hand uses log scale, with a grid that's an order of magnitude larger at each step.

Good spot, thank you. Will update now.

@lastchance this plot considered particles from the start of release. And yeah your description is entirely my confusion. I have been replicating other models in this document without issue and the plots are expected (curved). But this one is just linear, and you say, jumps before the end of release. I just don’t get why it does this.

If you print out the values of t at which the derivative is being evaluated you will find that they are much too far apart (i.e. the internally-estimated timestep is far too large). This is probably because the solution is not far away from two straight-line segments (the timescales involved are much shorter than the air-exchange time based on ventilation rate) and you have an unresolved discontinuity in the derivative there.
A quick fix (but better option at the bottom of this post) is to impose a maximum timestep (hmax) in your call to odeint:
solution = odeint(self.evaporation_ode, y0, t, hmax=0.1 )

This at least gives the correct large-time behaviour and release duration. Note that the t values that you give it are purely for output: they are NOT the ones used internally by the ODE solver.

(To some extent, the supposed "correct" solution appears to suffer from the same sort of problem).
There is no need to put a t value precisely at the release-duration time: it simply won't be used by odeint
Your problem appears to be analytically soluble should you prefer to do that.
Possibly Better Option
Another option is to solve it as a two-part problem: from time 0 until the release duration and then from release duration to the end of the simulation. Then you can avoid internal discontinuities in the time derivative.

Thank you. So are we saying we think the web app may very well be wrong? As a first order derivative it is odd to see this spike in the model.

I think the web app is simply using a large timestep (and I doubt there is much you could do about that). So - not fundamentally wrong, but numerically inaccurate. There is a discontinuity in the derivative at the end of the release (0.3 minutes). Either you use a timestep small enough for this to have negligible effect or you separately solve on either side of the discontinuity.
